# Cognito Forms: Why Doesn't an Export show Repeating Sections?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am accepting registrations for multiple players to sign up for a soccer program.  The repeating section allows the registrant to sign up multiple players by the "Add a Player" function.  However, when I export the entries, it does not include the information in the repeating sections, which is frankly all that I care about.  How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

[Repeating sections](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/repeating-sections) in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) are exported as separate sheets that link back to the parent sheet.  This allows you to have multiple repeating sections on the same form.